# Capturing filesystem globs using optparse

Tags: python, shell, glob

I'm working on some Python code which uses `optparse` to get the name of some input files, then (on paper) expands that input using `glob.glob()` if possible.

It seems however that my shell (`zsh`) expands the glob before it's passed to Python. For example, if I run `python myscript.py *.txt`, I'll get the first matching `.txt` file instead of the literal glob, `*.txt`. This is pretty useless to me.

I figure this is more of an issue on the shell side; but taking into account portability, I'd like to know if there's a Python-side solution to this.

`optparse` code used for this:

```
p = OptionParser()
p.add_option('-f', '--infile', dest='input', action='store', type='string')
(options, args) = p.parse_args()
```

The issue is reproducible with the following minimal example (which also shows that it extends to manual argument extraction using `sys.argv`):

```
$ ls *.txt
file1.txt    file2.txt    file3.txt
$ python -c 'import sys; print sys.argv' *.txt
['-c', 'file1.txt', 'file2.txt', 'file3.txt']
```

So again, for clarity, I'm looking for a way to pass the *glob literal* to my python code, to have it expanded there, using Python, because a shell workaround hurts portability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that's the only argument that you're passing, then the rest of the glob expansion is being sucked up by the positional args part of the parsing tuple, so maybe try to use that?

```
from optparse import OptionParser

p = OptionParser()
p.add_option('-f', '--filename', dest='input', action='store', type='string')
options, args = p.parse_args()

print options
print args
```

Gives you:

```
$ ls *.txt
failure_counts.txt  iscsi-targets.txt  README.txt  snmp.txt  success_counts.txt
$ python glob.py -f *.txt
{'input': 'failure_counts.txt'}
['iscsi-targets.txt', 'README.txt', 'snmp.txt', 'success_counts.txt']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can escape the wildcard character so that the shell doesn't do the globbing for you:

```
$ ls *.txt
file1.txt   file2.txt   file3.txt
$ python -c 'import sys; print sys.argv' *.txt
['-c', 'file1.txt', 'file2.txt', 'file3.txt']
$ python -c 'import sys; print sys.argv' \*.txt
['-c', '*.txt']
```

Comment: I'm aware of this; but is there a solution which wouldn't require the end user to escape special characters?

Comment: Or you can `set -f` but it's not clear why this would be better than the shell's  default behavior. Maybe the OP should explain why the default appears problematic?

Comment: @tripleee the default behaviour's problematic because if I were to build around the *shell* expanding globs before I get them, I'd have to rewrite a big chunk of my parser manually. It's just kind of a waste of time at this point, and this could end up being useful in the future, too.

Comment: But based on the answers in the question you linked to earlier, I will request that this question be closed.